# Microsoft Graph notification timeout and number of retries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we are using Microsoft Graph notification to monitor certain resource changes such as group creation/deletion, etc.

In the MS doc it says "Send a 202 - Accepted status code in your response to Microsoft Graph. If Microsoft Graph doesn't receive a 2xx class code, it will retry the notification a number of times."

We'd want to have a better understanding on how this works, such as what are the timeout values (how long does Graph wait before it re-sends the notification?), and how many times it retries (is it a guaranteed delivery?), etc. Can anybody help shed some light on this?